# "have come, now" vs "have now come"

Tags: adverbs, present-perfect, adverb-position

Are both these sentences correct, do they carry the same meaning? Can I place the adverb *now* in these positions? If not, why?

1. Tensions submerged earlier have come to the fore, **now**
2. Tensions submerged earlier have **now** come to the fore

Comment: Related: [Position of “now” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166708/position-of-now-in-a-sentence) and [“It is time now” or “It is now time”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121202/it-is-time-now-or-it-is-now-time)

Comment: The first looks awkward, but might well arise in speech (and thus a quote would require the same ordering). But the formal register argues quite strongly for the use of the second variant. Someone claiming that the first variant is actually ungrammatical would need to provide compelling evidence if they wished to be taken seriously. // @Shoe's answer at Mari-Lou's second linked thread above is highly relevant (though it spells out how complicated adverb positioning is).